# How to get string from edit text and pass to new activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to collect user input and pass it to another activity and display it using text view.

I have tried using the getText() and toString() functions and passing the intent, but when running the program the strings that should contain the user input is not displayed properly.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_in);

            //Collect user inputs and store them in strings
            noun1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noun1);
            pluralNoun =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pluralNoun);
            noun2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noun2);
            place = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.place);
            adjective = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.adjective);
            noun3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.noun3);

            firstNoun = noun1.getText().toString();
            nounPlural = pluralNoun.getText().toString();
            secondNoun = noun2.getText().toString();
            inputPlace = place.getText().toString();
            inputAdjective = adjective.getText().toString();
            thirdNoun = noun3.getText().toString();

            madLib ="Be kind to your " + firstNoun + "-footed " + pluralNoun + "\n" +
                    "For a duck may be somebody`s " + secondNoun + ",\n" +
                    "Be kind to your " + pluralNoun + " in " + inputPlace + "\n" +
                    "Where the weather is always " + inputAdjective + ".\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "You may think that this is the " + thirdNoun + ",\n" +
                    "Well it is.\t";

        }



        public void createStory(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivityIn.this,
                    MainActivityOut.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("story",madLib);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
```

I expect an output of a few sentences displaying the story with the words that the user entered but instead, I get the output pictured below:

[image: Actual Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass two Strings from one Activity to another Activity in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061438/how-to-pass-two-strings-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: Hi Yabba, welcome to SO, please have a research before placing a question. We already have many questions for this task :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve your **String** in your another activity called **MainActivityOut.class** using below code and pass that string to your text view.

```
String madLib = getIntent().getStringExtra("story");
yourTextView.setText(madLib);
```

Answer (score 0):

In matLib some of the variable you calling are not String but editText, that's why you have those weird result. Like pluralNoun... Try this naming convention, name all editText et..., all textView tv..., all button btn..., all imageView iv... This way you can avoid confusion about your variables.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing **`EditText`** Object inside string

```
madLib ="Be kind to your " + firstNoun + "-footed " + pluralNoun + "\n" +
                    "For a duck may be somebody`s " + secondNoun + ",\n" +
                    "Be kind to your " + pluralNoun + " in " + inputPlace + "\n" +
                    "Where the weather is always " + inputAdjective + ".\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "You may think that this is the " + thirdNoun + ",\n" +
                    "Well it is.\t";
```

pluralNoun is **`EditText`** Object

change code like

```
madLib ="Be kind to your " + firstNoun + "-footed " + nounPlural+ "\n" +
                        "For a duck may be somebody`s " + secondNoun + ",\n" +
                        "Be kind to your " + nounPlural + " in " + inputPlace + "\n" +
                        "Where the weather is always " + inputAdjective + ".\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "You may think that this is the " + thirdNoun + ",\n" +
                        "Well it is.\t";
```